# Why does ' npm start ' command does not work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I just created a new react app using ' npx create-react-app . ' in an empty folder, after that when I tried to start the application using ' npm start ' I got this error :

(node:9068) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9068) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewnxC.png)

Any solution?

Comment: Which node and npm versions do you have? Which OS?

Comment: Try to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again